# Why do I have to use a.any() or a.all() in this code?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

In this code below, I found that when I put a number it works, but when I put ndarray then it would post an error message.
Why do I have to use a.any() or a.all() in this case?

```
import numpy as np
def ht(x):
    if x%2 == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
ht(1)
```

[Example]
step(1): 1
step(np.array([1,2,3,4])) : The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? Remember `if` is python, a simple swich., no looping implied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when evaluating `if` statements, you have to pass in a `bool`.

```
if var:
   pass
```

`var` has to be of type `bool`.

if `x` is a number, then `x%2 == 1` is a `bool`.

if `x` is a `np.array`, then `x%2 == 1` is a `np.array` which isn't a `bool`, but rather an array of `bool`, in which each cell states whether `*that cell* %2 == 1`.

You can check if all elements in it are `truthy` (1) or if any of them are `truthy` with `np.all` or `np.any`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when `np.array([1,2,3,4])%2` is performed, the output is also in np array format - `array([1, 0, 1, 0])`. To check whether these individual array elements are 1 or 0, one has to use the `any()` or `all()` function. There is no problem when we pass a single element.

So, here is the modified code -

```
import numpy as np
def ht(x):
    
    if all(x%2 == 1): #denotes true when all modulus results are == 1
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
ht(np.array([1,2,3,4]))
```

Output for the above code is `0`

```
import numpy as np
def ht(x):
    
    if any(x%2 == 1): #denotes true when any modulus result is == 1
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
ht(np.array([1,2,3,4]))
```

Output for the above code is `1`